# How to check if two group representations are equivalent

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

If we have two representations of the same group $G$, say $\phi$ and $\psi$, they are called equivalent if a $U$ exists such that $U^{-1} \phi(g) U=\psi(g)$ holds for all $g$ in $G$.

However, given all matrices of $\psi$ and $\phi$, how to check whether such a $U$ exists?

Comment: How one checks this depends a lot on the concrete case. For example, over $\mathbb{C}$ it turns out to be enough to check that the representations have the same traces on all elements (and thus just check it on all conjugacy classes).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I know this, but how to find out a $U$

Comment: Finding $U$ is rarely very interesting (it is the existence that is of interest usually).

Comment: In fact finding $U$ is rarely discussed in books on representation theory, but it is a moderately difficult computational problem.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, If my group has infinite elements, will the same traces of every elements still guarantee equivalence of representations?

Comment: No, for infinite groups this no longer suffices. For example one can construct a non-trivial $2$-dimensional representation of the integers with same trace as the trivial $2$-dimensional representation (this is a nice little exercise).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, what if the group is compact?

Comment: And I assume you also want the representation to be continuous is some suitable topology? In that case I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations $\phi(g)U=U\psi(g)$ give linear equations on $U$. Then it's just a matter of finding one solution that's nondegenerate. In fact, it is enough to solve the equations for the generators of the group.